# UIElement.AddHandler

Tags: silverlight

Has this been removed from silverlight 3?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598899%28VS.95%29.aspx

I see documentation on how to use it, but when I try it says UIElement doesn't have an addhandler method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, seems to work for me..

```
    UIElement asdf = new Canvas();
    asdf.AddHandler(ucConveyor.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, TestFunction, false);
```

Can you paste your code?

Comment: and of course when trying to set this up on my home computer I didn't update completely to Silverlight 3 it does work!